# Android Asynctask and runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I recently tried to implement the project, openalpr, and it worked fine in its original code. But when I tried to modify it and add some functions, I ran into some problems.
This is its partial code:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = OpenALPR.Factory.create(MainActivity.this, ANDROID_DATA_DIR).recognizeWithCountryRegionNConfig("us", "", destination.getAbsolutePath(), openAlprConfFile, 10);

                Log.d("OPEN ALPR", result);

                try {
                    final Results results = new Gson().fromJson(result, Results.class);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (results == null || results.getResults() == null || results.getResults().size() == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not possible to detect the licence plate.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                resultTextView.setText("It was not possible to detect the licence plate.");
                            } else {
                                resultTextView.setText("Plate: " + results.getResults().get(0).getPlate()
                                        // Trim confidence to two decimal places
                                        + " Confidence: " + String.format("%.2f", results.getResults().get(0).getConfidence()) + "%"
                                        // Convert processing time to seconds and trim to two decimal places
                                        + " Processing time: " + String.format("%.2f", ((results.getProcessingTimeMs() / 1000.0) % 60)) + " seconds");
                            }
                        }
```

This worked fine. But when I tried to get the "results" before runOnUiThread, its could not detect correctly anymore.
Below is my modified code:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = OpenALPR.Factory.create(MainActivity.this, ANDROID_DATA_DIR).recognizeWithCountryRegionNConfig("us", "", destination.getAbsolutePath(), openAlprConfFile, 10);

                Log.d("OPEN ALPR", result);

                try {
                    final Results results = new Gson().fromJson(result, Results.class);
                    if(results!=null) Log.d("ShowTheResults",results.getResults().get(0).getPlate());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (results == null || results.getResults() == null || results.getResults().size() == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not possible to detect the licence plate.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                resultTextView.setText("It was not possible to detect the licence plate.");
                            } else {
                                resultTextView.setText("Plate: " + results.getResults().get(0).getPlate()
                                        // Trim confidence to two decimal places
                                        + " Confidence: " + String.format("%.2f", results.getResults().get(0).getConfidence()) + "%"
                                        // Convert processing time to seconds and trim to two decimal places
                                        + " Processing time: " + String.format("%.2f", ((results.getProcessingTimeMs() / 1000.0) % 60)) + " seconds");
                            }
                        }
```

I just can't figure out why the output will be different from the UI thread. Could anyone tell me how to correctly use the "results" in the background before I show it on the UI?

Comment: `AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {` ???? Never saw such a construct. Who invented that? Please explain what you are doing. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @greenapps I grabbed these from [link](https://github.com/SandroMachado/openalpr-android). I also searched this construct for a while and finally got it a little more.

Comment: Well i will not follow that link. You could not post a link to the java file where you saw it? You think we should do the work and effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using `AsyncTask`s in a very bad way. You want to execute a `Runnable` on an asynchronous thread and then you call `runOnUiThread` inside of it to process a result on the UI thread. Why not using `AsyncTask`s in the way they are meant to be used?

Create a new task and use its common methods: `doInBackground`, `onProgressUpdate`, `onPostExecute`. If the AsyncTask is executed on the main thread these last two are already called on the UI thread.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Results>() {
    @Override
    protected Results doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = OpenALPR.Factory.create(MainActivity.this, ANDROID_DATA_DIR).recognizeWithCountryRegionNConfig("us", "", destination.getAbsolutePath(), openAlprConfFile, 10);

        Log.d("OPEN ALPR", result);

       Results results = new Gson().fromJson(result, Results.class);
        if (results != null || results.getResults() != null || results.getResults().size() > 0)
            Log.d("ShowTheResults", results.getResults().get(0).getPlate());

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Results result) {
        if (results == null || results.getResults() == null || results.getResults().size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not possible to detect the licence plate.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            resultTextView.setText("It was not possible to detect the licence plate.");
        } else {
            resultTextView.setText("Plate: " + results.getResults().get(0).getPlate()
                    // Trim confidence to two decimal places
                    + " Confidence: " + String.format("%.2f", results.getResults().get(0).getConfidence()) + "%"
                    // Convert processing time to seconds and trim to two decimal places
                    + " Processing time: " + String.format("%.2f", ((results.getProcessingTimeMs() / 1000.0) % 60)) + " seconds");
        }
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for help me a lot. I just a beginner to android so I can't tell what's a good way. I will try it out in its ordinary way.

Comment: Ok, once tried remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: I tried. It work properly only if I comment out the line `if (results != null || results.getResults() != null || results.getResults().size() > 0)
            Log.d("ShowTheResults", results.getResults().get(0).getPlate());`in doInBackground. Debugger sometimes said the results is a null object and program crash. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Yes. If `results` is null the app tries to verify the second condition (`results.getResults() != null`), and here it crashes, because `results` is null. You should `and` conditions (&&) rather than `or` them (||); this way, if the first condition is false, it will not check the followings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am not sure about your Async Task implementation, but i can see what the problem is . Please check the below code.

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = OpenALPR.Factory.create(MainActivity.this, ANDROID_DATA_DIR).recognizeWithCountryRegionNConfig("us", "", destination.getAbsolutePath(), openAlprConfFile, 10);

                Log.d("OPEN ALPR", result);

                try {
                    final Results results = new Gson().fromJson(result, Results.class);
                    if(results!=null || results.getResults() != null || results.getResults().size() > 0) Log.d("ShowTheResults",results.getResults().get(0).getPlate());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (results == null || results.getResults() == null || results.getResults().size() == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not possible to detect the licence plate.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                resultTextView.setText("It was not possible to detect the licence plate.");
                            } else {
                                resultTextView.setText("Plate: " + results.getResults().get(0).getPlate()
                                        // Trim confidence to two decimal places
                                        + " Confidence: " + String.format("%.2f", results.getResults().get(0).getConfidence()) + "%"
                                        // Convert processing time to seconds and trim to two decimal places
                                        + " Processing time: " + String.format("%.2f", ((results.getProcessingTimeMs() / 1000.0) % 60)) + " seconds");
                            }
                        }
```